# Charged black hole horizon events and inverting sign of the metric component

Tags: black-holes

When studying a charged black hole what happens when the g00 component of the metric changes sign? Why do we have 2 horizon events? Someone could explain me this concept better. What does it means 'space and time invert their roles when g00 inverts sign' ?